# conversion of bytes to string

Tags: python, string

Im reading data from an tcp connection. If I read the data from wireshark(network monitor) I get 02501c41d11ec06a471102 but if I read data in python i get it in bytes:

```
b'\x02P\x1cA\xd1\x1e\xc0jG\x11\x02'
<class 'bytes'>
```

How do I convert this?
I tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import binascii
import time
import sys

TCP_IP = '10.20.0.195'
TCP_PORT = 9761
BUFFER_SIZE = 2048

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

while 1:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print (data)
    data2 = data.decode("utf-8")
    typ = type(data)
    print (typ)
```

but if in run this I get:

```
b'\x02P\x1cA\xd1\x00\x00\x02\xcb\x11\x00'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:/programeren/domotica/try again/receive.py", line 18, in <module>
    data2 = data.decode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 4: invalid continuation byte
```

just to be clear i want to turn

```
b'\x02P\x1cA\xd1\x00\x00\x02\xcb\x11\x00'
```

into

```
02501c41d11ec06a471102
```

Comment: You're starting with bytes. `.decode('utf-8')` means decode **from** UTF-8 to a unicode string. Also, it seems like both those strings are same-ish, the Wireshark one is just all formatted as hexadecimals, and  the Python one has a mixture of `\x` escapes and printable characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [binascii.b2a_hex](http://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii#binascii.b2a_hex) (or binascii.hexlify).

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.b2a_hex(b'\x02P\x1cA\xd1\x00\x00\x02\xcb\x11\x00')
b'02501c41d1000002cb1100'
>>> binascii.b2a_hex(b'\x02P\x1cA\xd1\x00\x00\x02\xcb\x11\x00').decode('ascii')
'02501c41d1000002cb1100'
```